Use rclone copy to upload files without preserving folder structure
I'm upload some files with this rclone command:
rclone copy --files-from files.txt / dropbox:main -P
rclone copy --files-from files.txt / dropbox:main -P --no-traverse
files.txt content:
/updates/file1
/updates/file2
When running the above command, it uploads the folder structure:
/main/updates/file1
/main//updates/file1
My goal is to upload only files to main folder without create same local structure:
/main/file1
/main/file2
